# Which statistical test can I run to making a stacked bar chart in SPSS of the means of two time measures for one IV?

Tags: regression

Hypothetical experiment:

I want to determine the "best" method of cooking chips - oven or fryer.

I have ten bags of chips, each bag I split in two, cook half in the oven, half in the fryer. for each bag, I rate the cooked chips out of ten for quality. I also time how long each method of cooking takes over all, as well as how long I physically spend cooking for each method.

I now have 6 columns X 10 rows of data. I want to compare the average quality score for each cooking method, and each length of time for each method.

But what test do I run, to compare the average time of cooking in conjunction with the average time I spend cooking, between the two methods? I have manually created a clustered bar chart, but really want to understand which statistical test to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an image of your data table? I think it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying statistical methodology is a hypothesis test.

In your situation, the simplest method is to run regressions separately for each method. Then after you obtained the coefficient and 95% confidence interval, you could indicate if the methodologies are significantly different from each other by checking if the coefficients are in the interval.

Consider a situation with two methods:
$$\beta_{1}= 1.05, and\ the\ confidence\ interval\ is\ [1.0,1.1]$$
$$\beta_{2}= 1.02, and\ the\ confidence\ interval\ is\ [0.97, 1.07]$$
Since $\beta_{2}$ fall into the interval of [1.0,1.1], they are the same statistically.